# Eclipse code collapsing bug

Tags: eclipse

I've been using Eclipse Indigo just fine for years, but I've recently had a problem where lines of code will randomly disappear. On top of that, the collapse/expand buttons on the side are disappearing for the code that's still there.

Line numbers example:

```
50
51
78
79
```

Also, someone's donated this picture showing the problem as well, although with fewer lines

[image: Screen Shot of bug]

Methods just get swallowed up and they *don't* show the first line like they would if you had collapsed them. And now for some methods that don't disappear, they're missing the little +/- signs on the side to collapse/expand them. However, if you click where the sign would be, it still works.

These problems affect random methods with no pattern, as far as I can tell. Is this some special "feature" of Eclipse? How do I fix this?

Comment: Try IntelliJ instead?

Comment: Same problem on Luna. That drive me crazy, some comments/tasks disappear while folding and the only way to get it back is to erase every line between to method... with huge file, I would love to be able to fold my code and javadoc without loosing some of it...

Comment: And my first time trying this feature, all the way in 2020, I have this issue and think I''m going crazy and hit backspace or something. Nope, just a bug that's been around for at least 7 years now with no solution or workaround.

Answer (score 1):

If you can live without code folding to work around this issue, you might want to disable it in the preferences.

- Java only: Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Folding -> Enable Folding
- All text editors: Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Structured Editors -> Enable Folding

Comment: While I appreciate the input, that's not exactly a solution.

Answer (score 0):

This happens every few hours for me. I've searched for a solution but haven't found one. I'm not entirely sure what causes this but it seems to only occur with code folding turned on. Restarting Eclipse is the only way I've found to temporarily fix the bug.